# Reducing the total size of a Bitmap in Android without loss of quality

Tags: android

How can I reduce the total file size (in Bytes) of a Bitmap in Android without a loss of quality?

Is it possible to Image filtering in Android programmability like: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html

Thanks, for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There are lossless compression techniques, quite a few of them.  Just choose one that you like, find a library that implements it, and put it to use.  We don't know what kind of images you are trying to compress, so we can't suggest the best one for you.

Comment: see i am drawing Bitmap Images on Canvas, but when no. of images more then an memory limit, got OutOfMemory Exception.
So I want to reduce size in terms of Bytes with same quality.

So we can draw more images then before.

pls suggest.

Comment: Anyone have idea about : what's the fastest way to draw "Bitmap" in Andorid.

Thanks